# Bibtex and Chicago style citations?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

In the [Chicago Manual of Style citation guidelines](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html) I find that one is to quote journal articles and italicize journals, books, and theses. But when I run the code below the output shows the journal article title as un-quoted. What's going on?

[image: output]

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*} 
  \bibliographystyle{chicago}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

and

```
% test.bib
@phdthesis{Doe11,
  title={The Title},
  author={Doe, J.},
  year={2011},
  school={University of Mars}
},

@article{JohSil05,
  title={EbayesThresh: R programs for Empirical Bayes Thresholding},
  author={Johnstone, I.M. and Silverman, B.W.},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Software},
  volume={12},
  number={8},
  pages={1--38},
  year={2005}
},

@book{Joh11,
    title = {Gaussian estimation: Sequence and multiresolution models},
    author = {Johnstone, Ian M.},
    year = {2011},
},
```

Example from the manual:

Joshua I. Weinstein, “The Market in Plato’s Republic,” *Classical Philology* 104 (2009): 440.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "un-quoted" instead of "un-italicized" here: "the output shows the journal article as un-italicized."?

Comment: Good catch. I see it's fixed. Thanks Gonzalo.

Comment: Are you sure that the quotes are required? The latest version of `biblatex-chicago` doesn't use quotation marks, and as far as I know it's quite up to date and follows the CMS quite closely.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I'm not certain quotes are required. That's just what I found in every online Chicago Manual of Style guide (up to 4 and counting). It could be that those guides are the ones that aren't up to date. I don't know. Hopefully someone knows.

Comment: @brianjd --- It depends on the specification.  Author-date styles do not use quotation marks for titles of articles or book chapters (etc.); in a notes-and-bibliography style, however, quotation marks are expected.  (Note also that, strictly speaking, the parentheses around the year for an author-date style is not part of the CMS style --- unless it has changed in the 16th edition, which I kind of doubt.  --- Let me also add that the example you give from the manual is a 'notes-and-bibliography' example.

Comment: @jon: Are you sure? The examples for author-date style given under "Journal Article" [here](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html) both show quotes.

Comment: @brianj --- You are right, judging from your link, but that is different from what CMS (15th ed.) says: § 16.97 [regarding reference lists]: _Titles: italics and quotation marks._ Titles of books and journals are usually italicized just as they would be in text or in a bibliography. Articles or chapters, however, are not enclosed in quotation marks. (Where quotation marks have been used consistently, however, they need not be deleted, except to conform to the needs of a particular journal or series.)  Note also that it is common to use 'sentence case' instead of 'title case' in these lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `biblatex-chicago` package with some extra modifications to implement this fairly easily.  The `biblatex-chicago` package recommends using `biber` for sorting instead of `bibtex`.

As some of the comments have noted, in the natural and behavioural sciences, I think quotation marks are rarely used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{Doe11,
  title={The Title},
  author={Doe, J.},
  year={2011},
  school={University of Mars}
},

@article{JohSil05,
  title={EbayesThresh: R programs for Empirical Bayes Thresholding},
  author={Johnstone, I.M. and Silverman, B.W.},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Software},
  volume={12},
  number={8},
  pages={1--38},
  year={2005}
},

@book{Joh11,
    title = {Gaussian estimation: Sequence and multiresolution models},
    author = {Johnstone, Ian M.},
    year = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}} % make article titles in quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % make theses italics
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

The guidance about quotation marks is a recommendation, not a requirement.  *Chicago* (16th, print edition) 15.45 explicitly gives freedom here:

> *Publications preferring sentence-style capitalization for titles.* Especially in the natural sciences, many publications that use a version of the author—date style prefer sentence-style capitalization ... In addition, works that prefer this style may eschew quotation marks for chapter or article titles.

As far as I can tell, these quotation marks are not used in the natural sciences at all; the wording ("many", "may") is one of those signs of *Chicago* clinging to the past.  It's normal in the humanities, though.

*Chicago* citation style is not supported that well by Bibtex, but in this case it should be easy to change `chicago.bst` to support these quotation marks if you want that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the words "easy" and ".bst" rarely coexist in the same sentence. :-) Could you add some code to show the modification?

Comment: I'm not sure about them 'clinging to the past' given that the 15th used sentence-style and the 16th at least permits, arguably encourages, quotation marks and non-sentence-style! (Maybe clinging to somebody else's past?)

Comment: @cfr: I mean they are reluctantly acknowledging a pattern (omission of quote marks) that has been dominant in the natural sciences for >3 decades.