# Suppress field using chicago bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

I am using the natbib package and chicago style to create my reference list. Some of the references in the bib file contain a field called "note" which is printed if I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

The bib references look like this:

```
@article{hambrick_influence_1996,
    title = {The Influence of Top Management Team Heterogeneity on Firms' Competitive Moves},
    volume = {41},
    copyright = {Copyright Â© 1996 Johnson Graduate School of Management, Cornell University},
    issn = {0001-8392},
    url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2393871},
    doi = {10.2307/2393871},
    number = {4},
    journal = {Administrative Science Quarterly},
    author = {Hambrick, Donald C. and Cho, Theresa Seung and Chen, {Ming-Jer}},
    month = dec,
    year = {1996},
    note = {{ArticleType:} research-article / Full publication date: Dec., 1996 / Copyright Â© 1996 Johnson Graduate School of Management, Cornell University},
    pages = {659--684}
}
```

How do I suppress this "note" field? Another follow-up question: is there a way to suppress the "month" field in the printed reference?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using the `annote` field, not the `note` field.  Also, if you will be a regular user of the Chicago style, you should consider switching from `natbib` to `biblatex` (and the new engine `biber`) to get a full and up to date implementation of the rather complicated Chicago specification.

Comment: @jon - Why should a user name the field `annote` rather than `note` -- other than for the simple expedient of making BibTeX not process a field whose name it's not programmed to recognize?

Comment: @Mico -- I though `note` was meant to be printed in the output, while `annote` will simply be ignored.  And the information in the example looks like stuff of interest to the database maintainer, but it certainly has no place in Chicago-style output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion jon. So there is no way in which I can included a command in the preamble that supresses the note field? I will be using Chicago style a lot, but I haven't quite figure out how biblatex works. I tried to get this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/bibtex-and-chicago-style-citations?rq=1) running but got the following warning messages: empty bibliography on input line 33. Any suggestions on good biblatex tutorials? Thanks.

Comment: @MdV -- Your error message is cryptic without an example to look at.  You can of course modify the existing `.bst` style (as shown in the answer below), but, aside from the fact that the style implements a very outdated version of the Chicago specification (i.e., one that no journal/publisher will accept today), since it is based on the rigid `bibtex` format, the `note` field might well be expected to do some real work in the bibliography output.  The recommended thing to do is to 'invent' a field (e.g., `annote`): the `.bst`/`bibtex` will ignore all fields it does not recognize.

Answer (score 6):

The bibliography style file `chicago.bst` is quite ancient; according to the header information given in the file, it was last updated in 1992 [!]. If you're stuck with `chicago.bst`, though, you may want to do the following:

- Find the file `chicago.bst` in your file system (likely under `../bibtex/bst/chicago`, where `..` is the root of the TeX distribution), make a copy and call the new file, say, `mychicago.bst`.
- Open `mychicago.bst` in your favorite text editor
- Search for the function `FUNCTION {output.year.check}` (it starts on line 266 in my copy of this file). In this function, replace the line

  ```
  { ", " * month * ")" * }
  ```

  with

  ```
  { ")" * }
  ```

  (I.e., make BibTeX do the same thing whether or not a `month` field is present in a given entry.)
- Regarding how (not) to process the contents of a `note` field (assuming one is present): For this case, I recommend that you go through each of the 12 instances of so of the following two lines

  ```
  new.block
  note output
  ```

  and choose which instances you want to comment out (using `%`, as usual) and which ones you want to keep. I could imagine you'd want to comment out these instructions for entries of type `@article` and `@book`, whereas you may well want to keep them for entries of type `@misc` and `@unpublished`.
- Save the file and update the TeX filename database if necessary. E.g., if you use TeXLive or MacTeX, you could type `texhash` at a command prompt.
- Use the bibliography style `mychicago` from now on.

Comment: @MdV - glad it worked well! Please don't be shy about upvoting and/or accepting my answer. :-)