# Full authors names in the list of unnumbered references and Chicago style citations?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I need to use Chicago style citations. The journal states the following relevant requirements:

1. The bibliography should contain each author's full name, as it is given in the publication being cited. Do not use first and middle initials only (unless the name is listed that way in the cited work).
2. The references must not be numbered in the bibliography.
3. In the main text, Author A and B should be cited as A and B and not as A & B.

**The journal suggests `\usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}. to be used and not biber.**

My problem is that I cannot comply with rule 1. I read about a solution with the package biblatex-chicago here [Bibtex and Chicago style citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/bibtex-and-chicago-style-citations) but in my case it is not practical because each reference must be typed before the main text, I have many references and they are in a bib file. I would like to avoid retyping them because it will be very time consuming. Below I provide what I did till the moment but I get in this way numbered references with abbreviated first name.

Example output:

> ```
> Baldwin, K. (2016). The paradox of traditional chiefs in democratic Africa. Cambridge University Press.
> Baldwin, K. and P. Raffler (2019). Traditional leaders, service delivery, and electoral 611 accountability. Decentralized Governance and Accountability, 61–90.
> ```

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem? If \usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago} is used, the command \bibliography{test-bib} cannot be used at the end of the document. How to correctly define it in this case? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,natbib,pdflscape,subfigure,array,hyperref, mathpazo, longtable,rotating, float, booktabs, lineno}

%\usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}

\normalem

\onehalfspacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]
\renewcommand{\thesubhyp}{\thehyp\alph{subhyp}}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}


@book{baldwin2016,
    title={{The paradox of traditional chiefs in democratic Africa}},
    author={Baldwin, Kate},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}


@article{baldwinraffler2019,
    title={{Traditional leaders, service delivery, and electoral accountability}},
    author={Baldwin, Kate and Raffler, Pia},
    journal={Decentralized Governance and Accountability},
    pages={61--90},
    year={2019}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum~\citep{baldwin2016}.
    Dolor sit amet~\citet{baldwinraffler2019}.
    
    {\nocite{*}  \bibliographystyle{chicago}
    \bibliography{\jobname} }

\end{document}
```

Comment: in case "retyping" refers to the filecontents environment in the answer you linked too: that is there only to make the answer selfcontained. You can naturally use your own external bib-file instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. You understood me correctly. I cannot orientate where and how to add my bibliography file if I use biblatex-chicago. Do you know?

Comment: With biblatex you add a test.bib-file with `\addbibresource{test.bib}` in the preamble.

Comment: I am very grateful for your useful answer. I experimented with what I learned so far, and have one final hurdle. I will very much appreciate if you answer me if you know.  Before asking I should say that I provided a better Latex reproducible example by editing the post. My final issue is that when I try to use \usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago} as suggested by the journal, the Latex file does not compile anymore. I unsuccessfully experimented with some modifications that I do not list due to space limits. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: If you want to use biblatex, remove natbib, \bibliography and \bibliographystyle. To print the bibliography use \printbibliography.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you very much! Everything worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage[abbreviate=true,%
    cmsbreakurl,%
    sorting=nyt,%
    maxnames=3,%
    minnames=1,%
    isbn=false,%
    url=true,%
    date=long,%
    cmsdate=both,%
    bibencoding=inputenc,%
    bibannotesep=vpar,
    booklongxref=bib,%
    longcrossref=bib,%
    related=true,%
    notes]
    {biblatex-chicago}
```